# Flashing text once in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like for a bit of text to flash once at say 1 second in. Have this code so far (which I gather bits from this site) - I have looked at the blinking function but i think this is my best option.

```
function flashtext(ele, col) {
    var tmpColCheck = document.getElementById(ele).style.color;
    if (tmpColCheck === 'white') {
        document.getElementById(ele).style.color = col;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(ele).style.color = 'white';
    }
}
setInterval(function () {
    flashtext('tdOne', 'blue');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: `<blink>Hey!  I'm an annoying web page!</blink>`

Comment: I am fully aware of how 'annoying' a flash can be, but i only want this to happen one rather than over and over again.

Comment: You say `white`, browser says `rgb(255,255,255)`. Clearly, not the same.

Comment: Unless you want your text to blink every second (instead of once), you want to use setTimeout instead of setInterval

Comment: SetTimeout didn't seem to work effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="example">Hello!</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var f = document.getElementById('example');
    setInterval(function() {
        f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
    }, 1000);

});
```

OR

if you want to call the function explicitly, use this -

```
function blink() {
   var f = document.getElementById('Foo');
   setInterval(function() {
      f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
   }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `visibility` may be a better property to play with, as it doesn't mess up layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in css alone i use it for the colons on a digital clock on a dashboard. see included fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cy6azatq/).

```
      p {
        -moz-animation: mymove 1s ease infinite;
        -webkit-animation: mymove 1s ease infinite;
        -ms-animation: mymove 1s linear infinite;
        -o-animation: mymove 1s linear infinite;
        animation: mymove 1s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes mymove {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; text-shadow: 0 0 20px #00c6ff; }
    50%{ opacity: 0; text-shadow: none;}
    100% { opacity: 1.0; text-shadow: 0 0 20px #00c6ff;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0% { opacity: 1.0; text-shadow: 0 0 20px #00c6ff; }
    50%{ opacity: 0; text-shadow: none;}
    100% { opacity: 1.0; text-shadow: 0 0 20px #00c6ff; }
}
```

Comment: What about the un-prefixed version, for people who are using Internet Explorer, hm?

Comment: I dont have a great understanding of prefixes but this should work for all browsers including ie [see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cy6azatq/2/)

Comment: IE does not understand `-moz` or `-webkit`. Considering those are the only two you put there, there is nothing left for IE to read.

Comment: theirs also -ms- and -o- in there so IE should be fine, i put the wrong fiddle link in originally but i have updated it.

Comment: `-ms-animation` has never existed. IE just supported it immediately.

Comment: A right i have just read up on that, so i wouldn't need to include -ms- anymore. Thank you that's good to know.